# insert_id not getting the current id

Tags: php, mysqli

I have been reading the other quotes regarding this and haven't found an answer. I'm trying to return the record id with `insert_id`:

```
$user = $db->query("
INSERT INTO users(user_name,user_email,user_password,user_salt,
    user_vMake,user_vModel,user_dateJoined,user_code)
VALUES ('".$userName."',
        '".$userEmail."',
        '".$hashedPassword."',
        '".$salt."',
        '".$userVMake."',
        '".$userVModel."',
        '".$userDateJoined."',
        '".$randomCode."')
    ");
#Add the user 
$newID = $user->insert_id;
```

If any one has any idea that would be great.

Comment: Try `$newID = $db->insert_id;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution in your case will be using `$newID = $db->insert_id;` instead of `$newID = $user->insert_id;`.

Answer (score 3):

`$db` is your database object, `$user` holds the return value of the query function. `insert_id` is a member of `$db` and is not a member of `$user`. So instead of:

```
$user->insert_id
```

use

```
$db->insert_id
```